# If an analytic $f$ satisfies any of these two conditions, then it is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying assignment questions of an institute in which I dont study. I am struck on these 2.

1. If $f$ is differentiable function from a region $X$ in $\mathbb{C}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ prove that $f$ is necessarily a constant.
2. If $f$ and $\bar {f}$ are both analytic in a region $X$ show that they are constant on region $X$.

Attempts:

1. Region is always open. So, range of $f$ must be open (open mapping theorem) but $\mathbb{R}$ is not open in $\mathbb{C}$  even if it is a singleton as complement of $\{x\}$ is not closed. So , I am confused on how I can prove the statement.
2. For 2 I dont have anything to show as I am really confused on which result to use due to $\bar{f}$ in question.

Kindly help.

Comment: Instead of using the non-trivial  Open MappingTheorem you can prove a) by just applying C-R equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof for 1) is correct. For 2), if both $f$ and $\bar{f}$ are holomorphic (differentiable), then so are $\mathrm{Re}(f)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(f)$, yet their ranges lie in $\Bbb{R}$. By what you proved in 1), both of these must be constant, hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: How is singleton set open in $\mathbb{C}$ . Sorry for this question but I am confused in it. I think it is not open as its complement is not closed in $\mathbb{C}$? So ,I thing its not open in $\mathbb{C}$ .Kindly tell what i am taking wrong .

Comment: @Ben a singleton set is not open in $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: So how My proof for 1 is correct ? I mapped region X(which is open ) to singleton set !!

Comment: @Ben just as you mentioned, since $f$ mapped an open region to a non-open set and $f$ is holomorphic, $f$ must be constant.

Comment: Oh ,I got it !!